# drf-yasg How to show sample response with with api?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, openapi, drf-yasg

How can I add [example responses -- (openapi doc)](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/adding-examples/) to my swagger doc using [**drf-yasg**](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) package?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [**`drf_yasg.openapi.Response`**--(drf-yasg doc)](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/drf_yasg.html#drf_yasg.openapi.Responses) with the help of [**`@swagger_auto_schema(...)`**--(drf-yasg doc)](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/custom_spec.html?#custom-spec-swagger-auto-schema) decorator as

```
from drf_yasg.utils import swagger_auto_schema
from drf_yasg import openapi
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView

response_schema_dict = {
    "200": openapi.Response(
        description="custom 200 description",
        examples={
            "application/json": {
                "200_key1": "200_value_1",
                "200_key2": "200_value_2",
            }
        }
    ),
    "205": openapi.Response(
        description="custom 205 description",
        examples={
            "application/json": {
                "205_key1": "205_value_1",
                "205_key2": "205_value_2",
            }
        }
    ),
}


class MyTestAPIView(APIView):

    @swagger_auto_schema(responses=response_schema_dict)
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response({"foo": "bar"})
```

**Schema rendered Result**

[image: Schema rendered Result]

## Update

> its keep loading and not showing anything

You may need to click on ***"Example Value"*** text if you are looking in ***Swagger*** doc

[image: loading spinner]

Comment: So I have to write custom response for every api ? I have 22 apis . so for all of them ?

Comment: Yes, unless any of them are returning the same response.

Comment: Sir , Can You tell how I can add post parameter in it as well ? I can't send post parameter

Comment: This is an *"another question"*, please do ask a new question regarding the new issue. BTW, please do accept and upvote the answer if you found this answer was helpful.

Comment: Then there must be some configuration issue in your case. This answer will work as-is @Fawad

Comment: In my case too, the examples is just loading and not showing anything.

Comment: Can you add a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce the issue? @DivyaKonda

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I posted more details as an answer. the comments seem to have a character limit

Comment: I expected a *new question* with a reference link @DivyaKonda

Comment: someone actually answered on git - https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/issues/86
seems to be a css issue.

Comment: @FawadRana I hope the update might be useful for you!!!

Answer (score 3):

In response to @JPG's response, there is a quick fix for that. Go to settings and add this.

```
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
    "DEFAULT_MODEL_RENDERING": "example"
}
```

This will render the example first.