# drf-yasg cover all responses to following implemented standard api response

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, drf-yasg

I did implement the standard API response such as [this article](https://agusmakmun.github.io/python/django/2020/01/07/django-standard-api-response-middleware-for-drf.html) in my app. And I also implement [drf-yasg](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg) for my API documentation. As we know the schema are using directly serializer to present the response. How I can cover all these below response examples by using drf-yasg schema?

**1. Success Single**

```
{
   "status": 200,                       # int : http status, can be 201, 200, etc.
   "success": true,                     # bool: boolean to identify the response is success or failed.
   "message": "The success message",    # str : string success message or null
   "result": {}                         # dict: a dict response data
}
```

**2. Success List**

```
{
   "status": 200,      # int : http status
   "success": true,    # bool: boolean to identify the response is success or failed.
   "message": null,    # str : string message or null.
   "results": [],      # arr : a list/array

   "count": 2,                                                   # int: all total result items
   "page_size": 5,                                               # int: maximum items per-page
   "current_page": 1,                                            # int: your current page
   "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/page/?page=2&search=a",    # str: string link or null.
   "previous": null                                              # str: string link or null.
}
```

**3. Error or Failed**

```
{
   "status": 400,                      # int : http status, can be 403,404,500,etc..
   "success": false,                   # bool: boolean to identify the response is success or failed.
   "message": "The failed message",    # str : string failed message or null
   "result": {}                        # dict: a dict response data
}
```

---

Currently I just did implement the general schema from drf_yasg, and still don't know how to do that.

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings

from rest_framework import permissions, authentication
from rest_framework.settings import api_settings
from rest_framework.routers import SimpleRouter

from drf_yasg import openapi
from drf_yasg.views import get_schema_view

from myproject.users.api.views import UserViewSet, AuthLoginView
from myproject.storage.api.views import FileViewSet

router = SimpleRouter()
router.register('users', UserViewSet, basename='api_users')
router.register('files', FileViewSet, basename='api_files')

app_name = 'api'
urlpatterns = [
    path('auth/login/', AuthLoginView.as_view(), name='api_auth_login'),
] + router.urls

if settings.DEBUG:
    swagger_info = openapi.Info(
        title='My Project API',
        default_version=api_settings.DEFAULT_VERSION,
        description='This is documentation of My Project open API',
        terms_of_service='https://foobar.com/tos/',
        contact=openapi.Contact(email='help@foobar.com'),
        license=openapi.License(name='Proprietary and confidential'),
    )
    schema_view = get_schema_view(
        info=swagger_info,
        public=True,
        permission_classes=(permissions.IsAdminUser,),
        authentication_classes=(authentication.SessionAuthentication,)
    )
    urlpatterns += [
        path('', schema_view.with_ui('swagger', cache_timeout=None), name='schema-swagger-ui'),
    ]
```

Comment: I see you have the default configuration as shown in the tutorial, have you tried to provide custom specifications? Located in you views as function decorators, these will allow you to specify for each view its specifications https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/custom_spec.html

Comment: Maybe this post already has the answers you are looking for?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64109297/drf-yasg-how-to-show-sample-response-with-with-api

Comment: @JeanBouvattier I have tried with above reference, but I need to make it global config response, instead of per-single views.

Comment: unrelated note: You might want to use drf-spectacular instead, as pointed out by the readme in drf_yasg

Comment: @rabbit.aaron hmm, sounds interesting. can you please provide an example please? especially for above case. mybe like modifying the `settings.DEFAULT_GENERATOR_CLASS`

Comment: All I can say is that I can recommend having a look at https://github.com/tfranzel/drf-spectacular

Comment: @KrzysztofSzularz let say we using it, what I should do then?

Comment: @binpy then you have `examples` in `extend_schema`: https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/drf_spectacular.html#drf_spectacular.utils.extend_schema

There are also standard responses to be configured.