# how to specify example value on drf-yasg swagger_auto_schema request_body?

Tags: python, drf-yasg

I everyone. My question is similar to the one planted
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64109297/drf-yasg-how-to-show-sample-response-with-with-api), but in this case I would like to do the same with the request_body parameter.
How can I add an example value for the request_body parameter, similary as it is done there with the response parameter?
Thanks for your attention and your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the example parameter. Look at this example:

```
request_schema_dict = openapi.Schema(
    title=_("Update order"),
    type=openapi.TYPE_OBJECT,
    properties={
        'ordered_items': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_ARRAY, description=_('Ordered items list'), 
            items=openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_OBJECT, description=_('Ordered item'),
                properties={
                    'item': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING, description=_('Item id'), example="123*123*0001"),
                    'quantity': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_NUMBER, description=_('Ordered quantity'), example=12.33),
                    'sequence_number': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_INTEGER, 
                    description=_('Sequence of item inclusion in the order.'), example=1),
                    }
            )
        ),
        'status': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING, description=_('Order status'), example=1, enum=[0,1,2,3,4,5]),
        'invoicing_date': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING, description=_('Invoice date'), 
        example="2022-05-27T12:48:07.256Z", format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ]"),
        'invoice_number': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING, description=_('Invoice number'), example="123456789"),
        'note': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING, description=_('Client user note'), example=_("Client user note")),
        'agent_note': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING, description=_('Agent note'), example=_("Agent note")),
    }
)

@swagger_auto_schema(request_body=request_schema_dict, responses={200: 'Order updated.'}) 
def put(self, request, id):
..............
```

This will generate the following output on swagger:
[image]